# css tricks for background image blur

Tags: html, css

i want to blur the background image only but it has made the content blur also and i tried to set up the z-index i guess its not working
here is the html and i need the solution with explanation please:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student-login</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="main-form">
            <h1>Student Login</h1>
            <form class="login">
                <input type="text" placeholder="*User name" name="user_name"></input><br>
                <input type="password" placeholder="*Password" name="user_name"></input><br>
                <input type="button" value="Login"></input><br>
                <div class="button"><a href="register.html">Register</a></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the css file:

```
.body{

            position: absolute;
            top: -20px;
            left: -20px;
            right: -40px;
            bottom: -40px;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            background-image: url("background.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
            filter:blur(5px);
            z-index: 0;
}
h1{
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
    color: #282828;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2%;
}
.main-form{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3%;
    height:auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    opacity: .6;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 4%;
    padding-right: 4%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.login input[type="text"]{

    width: 260px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #505050 ;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 2%;
}
.login input[type="text"]:focus{

    border: 1px solid #0033FF;
}

.login input[type="password"]{

    width: 260px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #505050 ;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 2%;
}
.login input[type="password"]:focus{

    border: 1px solid #0033FF;
}

.login input[type="button"]{

    width: 265px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #505050 ;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 2%;
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.login input[type="button"]:hover{

    background-color: #404040;
    color: white;
}
.button {

    width: 270px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #505050 ;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 2%;
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
    text-align: center;
}
.button a{

    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
    text-align: center;
}
.button:hover{

    background-color: #404040;
}
.button:hover a{

    color: white;
}

.login select{

    width: 265px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #505050 ;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 2%;
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.login select:hover{

    background-color: #404040;
    color: white;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/akademy/pen/FlkzB

Comment: i have already seen it but i want to find out due to which specific reason my code is making the whole thing blur.@johnnyarguelles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that FireFox's [3Ddomviewer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/3D_View) could help illustrate whats going on here. Moreover, what everyone is trying to say is that the blur is being applied to the `main-form id` as well b/c its a child of the body `div` that you are applying it to. Now, as for why z-index is not working (****Crackes knuckles****). Okay, so z-index ONLY WORKS ON ELEMENTS THAT HAVE A POSITION! in your main-form div the position isn't set to anything once you give it a position and set z-index to some large negative number it will disappear as it is being hidden by all of the other elements stacked on top of it. See [this](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) article for more info. I hope that helps.

Comment: Really thanks a lot @coderrick this really helped ..solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you said: `-webkit-filter: blur(5px)` and `filter: blur(5px)` in the body selector, that will blur the entire page... you only want to blur an image, so do this:

```
#imageSelector {
    -webkit-transform: blur(5px);
    transform: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: sorry probably i didnt get you here i used the name body for a division and the problem lies in the z-index property i can get that but i want to know the reason for which the z-index property isnt working?@Viraj Shah

Comment: for that, you would need to set a position for `.main-form` because z-index will only be applied to elements that have a defined position